# Is there any way to disable recording invocations with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have some tests, where I use Mockito mocks. I do not use verifications in the test at all. Now I would like to make some performance tests, and the mocks cause `OutOfMemoryError`. I could try to refactor the code to be able to "reset" the mocks. However it would be a lot easier, if Mockito could create mocks, which do not record their invocations. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  You want a "stub only" mock.

```
Xxxx mockXxxx = mock(Xxxx.class, withSettings().stubOnly());
```

This will make a mock of class `Xxxx` that will let you do stubbing, but not record any invocations.